# Jackson deserialize array of json objects ignoring some of the objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

Suppose I have this JSON Array

```
[{"type":"type1", "id":"1", "name":"John"},
 {"type":"type1", "id":"2", "name":"Jane", 
 {"type":"type2", "id":"3", "name":"Joseph"}]
```

And I have these Java objects

```
public class Person {
    Long id;
    String name;
    String type;
}

public class MainClass {
    List<Person> persons;
}
```

Is there a way to deserialize the JSON array such that only those that are type type1 will be included? Those with type2 should not be set as null but completely ignored.

Comment: You should have `type` member as well.

Comment: Added the type field. How will that help the deserialization?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve that with [Jackson Filter](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria)

Comment: I think Jackson Filter is for serializing an Object to Json.